# What will be font size of 100px text on xxxhpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi as per below described design?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, zeplin

I'm designer and I've designed mobile UI of resolution 1440*2560.

In design I have few text having 100px of font size. Just want to know what will be the font size of in each device like xxxhpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi.

I'm using https://zeplin.io to provide design element details to developer but somehow in some case it's shows different result of Pixel to SP conversation. So just want to know entire equation for this calculation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: Thanks @pskink for your quick response and for detail documentation. As I've Mentioned I'm designer and not much aware about the developer's background for it. My query is I'm getting different SP value in "Zeplin" and from "Developer's end".

Answer (score 1):

Question -> I have few text having 100px of font size. Just want to know what will be the font size of in each device like xxxhpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi ?

Answer -> Go with [Pixplicity](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter) ;)

Comment: Thanks @santhosh for your response. Still I have one query regarding "Zeplin tool" how their value can be different in this case.

Comment: @YashpalSindhav, Welcome :). And I have no idea on their design architecture. You may communicate with them regarding this.